# div's data-background attribute and image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I would like to put an image for the div's background like this, but it does not show up, no idea why and if it does not works in this way?

```
<div data-background="image.jpg></div>
```

It works if I add this style but I want to avoid this, would like to achieve just with data-background.

```
<div data-background="image.jpg" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');"></div>
```

EDIT:
The reason I would like to use that attribute is because of the CSS I have:

```
.landing [data-background] {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(1) {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(2) {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(3) {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(4) {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

It is from template and i am trying to create intro landing page slideshow 2x2 photo grid that changes...

This is why I do not want to have style because would be needed to create id for every div, or to keep this lines in html...trying to avoid both

Comment: What you want will not work, unless you want to add a script that will do the work ... which will slow down your page, so really not a good idea

Comment: Custom data attributes are for storing arbitrary data and won't generate any CSS

Comment: Are you using any parallax effect... to achieve this background

Comment: The only thing you can use data attributes for, besides script, is text using CSS `attr()`

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use `style="background-image: url('image.jpg');"`?

Comment: I updated my topic with more info that explains more, thanks for all the answers for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.landing {
  height: 100%;
}
.landing div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.landing div:nth-child(1) {
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.landing div:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.landing div:nth-child(3) {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
.landing div:nth-child(4) {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
  <div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
</div>
```

*Side note*

*You can still use that attribute in your CSS, though recommend to do as my first sample*

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.landing {
  height: 100%;
}
.landing [data-background] {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(1) {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(2) {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(3) {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

.landing [data-background]:nth-child(4) {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
  <div data-background style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
  <div data-background style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
  <div data-background style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
  <div data-background style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `div{ background-image: url("image.jpg"); }`
in your css file?

As mentioned...data attributes not good for styling purposes.

Comment: I just updated my topic with more info that explains why I want to avoid that